# Can't compile project after adding SFML.NET by Nuget

Tags: visual-studio-2012, nuget, sfml.net

After adding SFML.NET through Nuget Packge manager I got the following error:

```
Error   4   The "UnzipNuspec" task was not found. Check the following: 1.) The name of the       
task in the project file is the same as the name of the task class. 2.) The task class is     
"public" and implements the Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask interface. 3.) The task is     
correctly declared with <UsingTask> in the project file, or in the *.tasks files located 
in the "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319" directory.
```

I'm using Visual Studio 2012.

As pointed out in other similar questions, I've tried to close and open MSVS, it didn't helped. 
I also checked out the build tools path in the registry, and it points to right directory.
I tried to install and uninstall Nuget packeage.

I found out that error possibly somehow connected to it's dependency : Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output, but I can't find out how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in their build script.

Go to the packages folder for your solution and locate the following file:

```
Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.1.0.6\build\net40\Baseclass.Contrib.Nuget.Output.targets
```

Around line 84 in that file you'll find a couple of `<Using Namespace=... />` tags.  Add this after those, before the `<Code...>` tag:

```
<Using Namespace="System.Threading" />
```

I've reported this on their github issues list as well.

Comment: One more step - reopen Visual Studio (may be reopen solution is enough, but didn't tried it).